# Get inserted uniqueidentifier from table B when its inserted from Table A insert trigger

Tags: database-trigger, sql-server-2017

I wasnt sure how to open the title but let me explain what is my problem.

I have two tables and both of them used uniqueidentifier as Id and they are auto generated by newsequentialid()

Now, when i make an insert to table B, it runes Insert trigger and i do some specific things inside this trigger and i also insert some values to another table called A and i need to retreive this table A's inserted Id but i am unable to find a solution.

Also let me explain why i need such a trigger. When a user creates an invoice with products in it where they have stock information, this trigger is responsible to create a stock transaction with header and detail about the products inserted (this stock detail table also has a trigger and it updates the warehouses) etc. etc.

i hope this gives some hint what i am trying to do

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[IT_TBLDebitInvoiceDetails] ON [dbo].[TBLDebitInvoiceDetails] AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @cnt int;
    --HEADER
    declare @DocumentId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @OrganizationId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @Date date;
    declare @TermDate date;
    declare @DespatchDate date;
    declare @DespatchNo nvarchar(20);
    declare @WarehouseId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @CustomerId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @StockId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @CurrencyTypeId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @GrandTotal money;
    --Auditable
    declare @WhoCreated uniqueidentifier;
    declare @DateCreated datetime;
    declare @WhoUpdated uniqueidentifier;
    declare @DateUpdated datetime;
    --DETAIL
    declare @ProductId uniqueidentifier;
    declare @Quantity decimal(18, 2);
    declare @ProductType int;

    SELECT TOP(1) @OrganizationId = OrganizationId, @DocumentId = A.Id, @Date = A.[Date], @TermDate = A.TermDate, @DespatchDate = A.DespatchDate, @DespatchNo = A.DespatchNo,
    @WarehouseId = A.WarehouseId, @CustomerId = A.CustomerId, @GrandTotal = A.GrandTotal,
    @WhoCreated = A.WhoCreated, @DateCreated = A.DateCreated, @WhoUpdated = A.WhoUpdated, @DateUpdated = A.DateUpdated
    FROM TBLDebitInvoices AS A
    INNER JOIN inserted AS B ON A.Id = B.InvoiceId

    /* CHECK STOCK TRANSACTION */
    SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM inserted AS A
    INNER JOIN TBLProducts AS B ON B.Id = A.ProductId
    WHERE B.ProductType != 1

    --we have products for stock, create stock header
    IF(@cnt > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TBLStocks (OrganizationId, TransactionType, DocumentType, DocumentId, [Date], DeliveryDate, DeliveryNo, SourceWarehouseId, CustomerId, [Description], WhoCreated, DateCreated, WhoUpdated, DateUpdated, IsDeleted)
        VALUES (@OrganizationId, 5, 0, @DocumentId, @Date, @DespatchDate, @DespatchNo, @WarehouseId, @CustomerId, '', @WhoCreated, @DateCreated, @WhoUpdated, @DateUpdated, 0);

        SELECT @StockId = ???????;
    END

    INSERT INTO TBLStockDetails (StockId, ProductId, [Value])
    SELECT @StockId, ProductId, SUM(Quantity) FROM (
        SELECT A.ProductId AS ProductId, A.Quantity  FROM inserted AS A
        INNER JOIN TBLProducts AS B ON B.Id = A.ProductId
        WHERE B.ProductType = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C.IngredientID, A.Quantity * C.Quantity FROM inserted AS A
        INNER JOIN TBLProducts AS B ON B.Id = A.ProductId
        INNER JOIN TBLProductRecipes AS C ON C.ProductId = B.Id
        WHERE B.ProductType = 2
    ) AS T1
    GROUP BY ProductId;

    UPDATE TBLDebitInvoices SET StockId = @StockId WHERE Id = @DocumentId;

    /* CHECK DC TRANSACTION */
    INSERT INTO TBLDebitCreditTransactions (TransactionType, DocumentType, DocumentId, PaymentStatus, [Date], Amount, AccountType, AccountId, CurrencyTypeId)
    VALUES (1, 0, @DocumentId, 0, @TermDate, @GrandTotal, 0, @CustomerId, @CurrencyTypeId);
END
GO
```

inside this trigger i have this insert:

```
INSERT INTO TBLStocks (OrganizationId, TransactionType, DocumentType, DocumentId, [Date], DeliveryDate, DeliveryNo, SourceWarehouseId, CustomerId, [Description], WhoCreated, DateCreated, WhoUpdated, DateUpdated, IsDeleted)
VALUES (@OrganizationId, 5, 0, @DocumentId, @Date, @DespatchDate, @DespatchNo, @WarehouseId, @CustomerId, '', @WhoCreated, @DateCreated, @WhoUpdated, @DateUpdated, 0);

SELECT @StockId = ???????;
```

and i need the Id inserted to this table so i can use its id to insert its row elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems i found the answer, i wasnt sure inserted statement will give a separate result for the second insert, but it works

```
DECLARE @IdTable TABLE (StockId uniqueidentifier);

INSERT INTO TBLStocks (OrganizationId, TransactionType, DocumentType, DocumentId, [Date], DeliveryDate, DeliveryNo, SourceWarehouseId, CustomerId, [Description], WhoCreated, DateCreated, WhoUpdated, DateUpdated, IsDeleted)
    OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @IdTable(StockId)
    SELECT @OrganizationId, 5, 0, @DocumentId, @Date, @DespatchDate, @DespatchNo, @WarehouseId, @CustomerId, '', @WhoCreated, @DateCreated, @WhoUpdated, @DateUpdated, 0;

    SELECT @StockId = StockId FROM @IdTable;
```

this will give the second table inserted uniqueidentifier